# Selfhosted PHP CRM (framework)

Tags: open-source, php, self-hosted, crm

I am looking for an open source, PHP-based CRM system (or a framework). The requirements for the CRM are:

1. **Email marketing campaign**. 
   So creating newsletter templates, defining image-tags in order to check if a user has loaded the newsletter, send newsletters, generate click-tags for specific campaigns, see results and so on …
2. **User activity**. 
   Managing (import/export/edit) User lists with user activities, like purchased items or usage of a service like a newsletter or even app notfications …
3. **User login in a Web portal/app**. 
   So the user should be able to login in a website portal and see some of his data.

In my search, I have looked into different "best CRM lists" and what I found were these:

- zurmo
- suitecrm
- espocrm

Later the system will have an API and will be attached to the DB of mobile app users.

None of these systems has what I need, but at least I would like to us a framework that is best suited for my task and can be extended.

Could you please help me to find the right one?

Comment: I don't use a CRM myself, so can't recommend one, but https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=crm gives 1,328 hits, so  ought to yield something. If you do find wsomehting there, pelase post an answer here to help others in future

Comment: thanks - what I am searching for could be here: [sourceforge.net/directory/language:php/os:linux/?q=crm](http://sourceforge.net/directory/language:php/os:linux/?q=crm) since I need PHP - I will look into it

Comment: Soudns good. Don't foget to know how it goes

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the "UPDATE" section and post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search and try I came to a hybrid solution:

1. Using mautic.org for marketing
2. Using metabase.com for reporting and data analysis
3. Using userfrost for user administration

All these projects can be combined and used as self hosted solution

Answer (score 1):

[CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org) might fit your needs.  It is open source, php and can be self-hosted.  To your points:

1. Email marketing - it handles bulk emails and the new
   'Mosaico' integration provides a flexible interface for designing
   mails.  It also has some A-B Testing features.
2. Activities - activities are added automatically for some things
   (like bulk mail, event registrations etc) or can be added manually.  You
   can customise the list of available activities.
3. User Login via Web - all user access is via a browser

The core product does a lot more and there is a wide range of optional extensions available.